# Pandas: DataFrame only with aggregated rows

Tags: python, pandas, etl

I have this DataFrame:

```
User   Measure1   Measure2
------------------------
User3         1          2
User1         5          3
User2         2          4
User2         4          1
User3         6          2
User1         4          0
```

And I wish a dataframe ( new or even the same ) with only aggregated values:

```
User   AggrMes1   AggrMes2
------------------------
User1         9          3
User2         6          5
User3         7          4
```

I already know how to groupby and aggregate the values with this code:

```
frame['AggMes1'] = frame.groupby( 'User' )['Measure1'].transform(np.sum)
frame['AggMes2'] = frame.groupby( 'User' )['Measure2'].transform(np.sum)
```

But this code only append the new columns in all rows, and I wish a dataframe with only aggregation rows.  If I drop the Measure1/Measure2 column I will still with all rows . I searched in documentation and other posts and don't found the solution.

EDIT: The Dataframe has many other columns that will receive other type transformations like subtraction, max, min, not only sum, so I need a column by column treatment

Best Regards,
Luis

Comment: `frame.groupby('User').sum()`.

Comment: You can slice the columns from the updated dataframe

Comment: @QuangHoang, I did this and the 'User' column aren't in my new dataframe, I have only my aggregated column. In my real case I group by for more than one column, and my frame are only with my aggregated column using your suggestion

Comment: @gomeslhlima chain with `.reset_index()`.

Comment: @EXODIA, If I drop the other columns, I remain still with multiples rows, not only the aggregated

Comment: @QuangHoang, thank you! work perfect! I edited the post with a new information, my dataframe has many measures, and not all measures will be sum. Do you know row to do the same thing in a column by column approach?

Comment: `frame.groupby('User').agg({'col1':'sum', 'col2':'min', 'col3':'max', 'col4':'mean'})`. Also read the doc for groupby named agg

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you so much